# 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xad in position 28: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, unicode, ascii, text-processing

I am implementing the app where i have one scenario ,that is to read the file after normalising it but while reading the file i am getting the following error : Below is my Try

```
  def unicodeToAscii(self,s):
        return ''.join(c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD',s) if unicodedata.category(c)!='Mn')

def normalizeString(self,s):
        s=self.unicodeToAscii(s.lower().strip())
        s=re.sub(r"([.!?])",r" \1",s)
        s=re.sub(r"([^a-zA-Z.!?])",r" ",s)
        s=re.sub(r"(\s+)",r" ",s).strip()
        return s

dataFile=os.path.join('/home/amit/Downloads/cornell_movie_dialogs_corpus/cornell movie-dialogs corpus','formatted_movie_lines')
print('please wait .. reading a file') 

lines =open(dataFile).read().strip().split('\n')
vocal=Vocabulary()
pairs=[[vocal.normalizeString(unicode(s))for s in pair.split('\t')] for pair in lines]
print('done reading')
```

Error:

```
please wait .. reading a file
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-4142a7dbef84> in <module>()
    118 lines =open(dataFile).read().strip().split('\n')
    119 vocal=Vocabulary()
--> 120 pairs=[[vocal.normalizeString(unicode(s))for s in pair.split('\t')] for pair in lines]
    121 print('done reading')
    122 

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xad in position 28: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: What's in `unicodeToAscii()`?

Comment: @tripleee i have updated the code , I am 100% sure the code is breaking because of unicodeToAscii when i don't call this method then there is no error . dunno when i am explicitly calling unicodeToAscii() method it's working fine but from the normalizeString() method when i am calling then it's through me the error

Comment: Do you have a reason to want to get rid of Unicode? The sane approach is probably simply to make your code work correctly with proper Unicode input.

Comment: actually i am implementing the text processing so i need to remove the unicode character if exist , i am doing because i have to train my model in the LSTM if there is  unicode character then accuracy rate will decrease

Comment: Issue itself has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Answer (score 0):

The Unicode normalization you are performing is *not* converting everything to ASCII.  It simply applies a Unicode normalization which makes sure that [variant encodings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) all are expressed the same way.  (In addition, you are avoiding this for the `Mn` category, so the normalization is incomplete, too.)

For what it's worth, [U+00AD](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00ad/index.htm) is a soft hyphen, which -- like the vast majority of Unicode characters -- does not have a corresponding pure ASCII character, though you could approximate it with a regular dash/minus/hyphen `-`.  The built-in `'replace'` functionality will simply replace it with a question mark, though:

```
>>> '\00ad'.encode('ascii', 'replace')
b'?'
```

Comment: "done" what exactly, and what are you hoping to actually do?